# what are these parameters in application.desktop?

Tags: unity, launcher

I set up a custom launcher in .local/share/applcations by copying and modifying one of the launchers in /usr/share/applications

It works fine but I was wondering what the meaning of parameters are that are passed along after `Exec=program` 
such as %f, %F, %c, %U?

Is there a manpage or a list somewhere that explains these parameters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The Exec key must contain a command line. A command line consists of
>   an executable program optionally followed by one or more arguments.
>   The executable program can either be specified with its full path or
>   with the name of the executable only. If no full path is provided the
>   executable is looked up in the $PATH environment variable used by the
>   desktop environment. The name or path of the executable program may
>   not contain the equal sign ("="). Arguments are separated by a space.
>
> **%f**
>
> A single file name, even if multiple files are selected. The system
>   reading the desktop entry should recognize that the program in
>   question cannot handle multiple file arguments, and it should should
>   probably spawn and execute multiple copies of a program for each
>   selected file if the program is not able to handle additional file
>   arguments. If files are not on the local file system (i.e. are on HTTP
>   or FTP locations), the files will be copied to the local file system
>   and %f will be expanded to point at the temporary file. Used for
>   programs that do not understand the URL syntax.
>
> **%F**
>
> A list of files. Use for apps that can open several local files at
>   once. Each file is passed as a separate argument to the executable
>   program.
>
> **%c**
>
> The translated name of the application as listed in the appropriate
>   Name key in the desktop entry.
>
> **%U**
>
> A list of URLs. Each URL is passed as a separate argument to the
>   executable program. Local files may either be passed as file: URLs or
>   as file path.

For complete detail see [Desktop Entry Specification](https://developer.gnome.org/desktop-entry-spec/)

<sup>Source:[Desktop Entry Specification](https://developer.gnome.org/desktop-entry-spec/)</sup>